# Proof explanation: Helmholtz theorem

Tags: electrostatics, potential

In the proof of Helmholtz theorem on page 556 of Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, he states that:

> At the large $r'$ limit, where $|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r| \approx r'$, the integrals:
>
> $$U(\mathbf r)\equiv\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\frac{D(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|}d\tau',\text{ and }\mathbf W(\mathbf r)\equiv\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\frac{\mathbf C(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|}d\tau',$$
>
> have the form  $$\int^\infty\frac{ X( r')}{ r'}r'^2dr'.$$

Why do the integrals have this form when $r'$ is large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Griffiths is considering cases where $\mathbf r$ is in the support of the charge and current distributions, and $\mathbf r'$ is very far from it. This means that, to leading order,
$$
|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|
=\sqrt{{ r'}^2-2\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r'+ r^2} 
= r'\left(1-\frac{\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r'}{r'^2}+O(r^2/r'^2)\right)
\approx r',
$$
since $r/r'\ll 1$. In turn, this means that you can substitute the script $r$'s in the denominator (equal to $|\mathbf r'-\mathbf r|$, and not typesettable over MathJax) with simply $r'$. That's all that's going on, really.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain why there is $r'^2$ in the integrand?

Comment: @chen What $r'^2$ in what integrand? If you mean the equation in my answer, that's just the Newton binomial theorem applied to the square root.

Comment: Sorry I did't make it clear.Could you explain why there is $r′^2$ in the integrand of  $\int^\infty\frac{ X( r')}{ r'}r'^2d\tau'$

Comment: That was a typo on your part - it's the volume element, which goes as $d\tau' = r'^2 \,dr'$. The angular integral has been included into the definition of the $X(r')$.

Comment: Thank you.In your answer, do you mean Griffiths is considering cases where the field point is still under the influence of the source point although very far from the source point?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what's going on (though 'very far' doesn't actually need to be that far).

Comment: Thanks.Does it mean the integrals in the other cases don't matter when considering whether the integrals converge or not? Could you explain the reason ?

Comment: @chen What integrals in what other cases?

Comment: In cases where r' doesn't approximate |r'-r|, the integrals U(r) and W(r).

Comment: @chen I'll have to refer you to the text for further details.